# Entity framework error when binding entities to multiple database contexts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, ninject, repository-pattern

I do not find correct way in my MVC app how to bind repositories and all EF related data. The example below create new DbContext for every IRepository and this give me error

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker

This error appears because my Entities in different context. For example the code(it is in Entity) will give error

```
var user = new User();
_userRepository.Insert(user) 

var order = new Order();
order.User = user;
_orderRepository.Insert(order) 
_unitOfWork.Commit();
```

If I change

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(DbContext)).ToMethod(context => new DbContext(connectionString));
```

to

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(DbContext)).ToMethod(context => new DbContext(connectionString)).InRequestScope();
```

I get error

```
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

if i use ServiceRepository in separated thread.

Maybe someone know solution?

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Entities"].ConnectionString;            
kernel.Bind(typeof(DbContext)).ToMethod(context => new DbContext(connectionString));            
kernel.Bind<IObjectSetFactory>().ToMethod(c => kernel.Get<DbContextAdapter>());
kernel.Bind<IObjectContext>().ToMethod(c => kernel.Get<DbContextAdapter>());  
kernel.Bind(typeof(IUnitOfWork)).To(typeof(UnitOfWork));
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
kernel.Bind<IServiceRepository>().To<ServiceRepository>();


 public interface IServiceRepository
    {
        UserDetail GetUser(int id);
        User GetUser(string email);
        User GetUser(string email, string password);
        OrderDetail GetOrder(string id);
        IEnumerable<OrderDetail> GetOrders(int userId);
        IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts();
        UserDetail GetParentUser(string partialEmail);
        IEnumerable<UserDetail> GetChildUsers(int parentId);
        IEnumerable<Statistic> GetStatisticForCurrentMonth(string ip);
        void InsertStatistic(QueueItem queueItem);
        void InsertStatistic();
        void Commit();
        void AddUser(User model);
        User AddUser(string firstName, string lastName, string email, string password, string country, int? parentId = null, DateTime? dateStamp = null);
        void AddOrder(Order order);
        void DeleteUser(int id);
        void DeleteUser(string email);
        bool OrderManager(PaymentProcessorOrder order, out User newUser, out Order newOrder);
        User AuthenticatedUser();
        string AuthenticatedUserEmail();
        bool ValidateUser(string email, string password);
        string GetPassword(string email);
    }


 public class ServiceRepository : IServiceRepository
    {
        private readonly IRepository<User> _userRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<Order> _orderRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<UserDetail> _userDetailRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<Statistic> _statisticRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<Product> _productRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<OrderDetail> _orderDetailRepository;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private static readonly object Locker = new object();

  public ServiceRepository(IRepository<User> userRepository, IRepository<Statistic> statisticRepository, IRepository<UserDetail> userDetailRepository, IRepository<Order> orderRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IRepository<OrderDetail> orderDetailRepository, IRepository<Product> productRepository)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _userRepository = userRepository;
            _statisticRepository = statisticRepository;
            _userDetailRepository = userDetailRepository;
            _orderRepository = orderRepository;
            _orderDetailRepository = orderDetailRepository;
            _productRepository = productRepository;
        }

//Skip code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use threads in an ASP.NET application because it gives you many problems. E.g. when IIS recycles you App Pool or suspends the application your threads will be terminated leaving your application in an inconsistent state. Or an uncatched exception in your thread can tear down your whole application.

Usually, you should implement async things in a separate service application so that IIS just has to send some message which will be processed asyncronously be this service. This will also solve your problem as you can use an other DbContext for each message.

If you really want to use background threads then you have to use different bindings for the DbContext for your requests and threads. E.g.

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(DbContext)).ToMethod(context => new DbContext(connectionString)).InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind(typeof(DbContext)).ToMethod(context => new DbContext(connectionString)).WhenInjectedInto<MyTask>();
```

But this means you can't pass entities from the request DbContext to the background thread context.

Answer (score 0):

You should't pass objects from one DbContext to another. This is not supported in EF (except if you detach and attach).

I would suggest to use the same DbContext in every repository, and keep the repositories on the same thread.

Comment: I do not want to pass objects from one DbContext to another, I want to keep them in one DbContext. SO I am asking the question how to do that.

Comment: What I see you are doing, is creating a DbContext per repo, am I right ?

Comment: If you pass objects from a repo to another, having a DbContext per repo, than you ARE "passing objects from one DbContext to another"

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here is using multiple repositories when you dispose of one it is also disposing the DbContext. You are right in thinking you can use a singleton instance of your DbContext (or per session)

[Ninject: Singleton binding syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581521/ninject-singleton-binding-syntax)

However, on your dispose of your repository you need something along the lines of:

```
public void Dispose(bool AllResources)
{
     if(AllResources)
     {
          _context.Dispose();
     }
     //Clean-up other resources
}
```

One of your other approaches you can use is to put the Disposable on your factory so when you execute off multiple repositories you would have:

```
using(var RepoFactory = new RepositoryContextFactory())
{
     var repo1 = RepositoryOne(RepoFactory.FetchContext());
     var repo2 = RepositoryTwo(RepoFactory.FetchContext());
     //Do work
}  //Your context would then be disposed of in the closure of the using across all Repositories instead of per repository which will allow you to reuse the same context across multiple repositories.
```

Hopefully this helps out on some level.

Comment: I wrote that I have tried .InRequestScope() but I do not think it is possible to use singleton instance of DbContext in web application due to multithreading.

Comment: The problem is your Repository is doing away with your Context after the repository closes, thus the error you are getting with the object has already been disposed.  You have to make a single context be used across all repositories and change your repository pattern to NOT dispose the DbContext!!!!!! It must be closed outside the repository pattern.

Comment: Tomas: As for your comment that a single instance of DbContext in a web app is a bad thing, you are right. The pattern I prefer is one instance per request, although you must be certain not to use is from many threads.